# LNK1104 Visual Studio 2019 using Libcurl

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libcurl

I'm currently trying to get curl running, currently I have a simple demo project running to test reading the document body of a webaddress.

I'm getting the LNK1104 fatal error, and frankly I'm not sure what have gone wrong, it did work but I can't remember changing anything and thus I've reached a blockage.

I tried looking the error up, and I've tried capsulating paths to the library directories with quotation marks, but this didn't help as well. I use MFC in a Static Library, and inside C/C++ (General) I include the include/curl/ directory. I do it for both debug (32 & 86) and release (32 & 86) releases with their respective directories.

Same goes for linker, inside Linker > Input in Additional Dependencies I do the same, just for the lib directory. And it seems this is what is doing me harm, the exact error message I'm getting is:

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\curl-7.72.0\x32 Debug\lib.obj'

I have tried most of the plausible solutions that I could find, without any luck. I somehow have an expectation of others stumbling upon the same error using libcurl. I do notice there is a space in the directory name, but as mentioned it did work before, and I've also tried with quotations.

For more information, I'm running Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition.

I'd really appreciate any help in trying to figure out the cause and come up with a solution, thanks a lot.

Comment: `Additional Dependencies`  is supposed to be a library file not a directory.

Comment: I have no clue how I missed this, honestly I tried this, and the documentation I looked at showed nothing like this. - You're a star, thanks for the timely help!

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you could write it as answer and mark it. Because this will be beneficial to other community.